# Fault with appending item to drop down (local storage)

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I have the following code, which works well.

```
<div style="padding:2px;">
  <form action='test.php' name ='gen' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='pass' placeholder="Insert website" size="10">&nbsp;<input type='submit' value='Open'>
  </form>
</div>
<?php
  $random = 'specificsaltcode'; // specific salt
  $pass2  = $_POST['pass'] . $random; // add it to user input
  $pass   = md5($pass2); // md5() both
  $url    = 'http://www.website'.$_POST['pass'].'random'.$pass.'randomurlcontinued'; // the url you need

  echo '<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" scrolling="yes" src="' . $url . '" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 26px;" width="99%" height="88%" border="0"></iframe>';
?>
```

This hashes a user input string and sends the original input string, along with the hashed number to an iframe as a url. This works well for me.

However, rather than send the url to an iframe, I need to send this to a drop down list and store it using local storage.

I have the following code for my drop down.

```
<style>
  #choice option { color: black; }
  .empty { color: gray; }
</style>
<script>
  var VM  = function () {
    this.annotationList = ko.observable();
    this.area = ko.observableArray();
    this.append = function () {
      this.area.push(this.annotationList());
      localStorage.setItem('labelObject',this.annotationList());
      localStorage.setItem('labelObjectList',this.area());
    };
  };

  var existAnnotationmodel = new VM();

  ko.applyBindings(existAnnotationmodel);
</script>
<script>
  $("#choice").change(function () {
    if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
    else $(this).removeClass("empty")
  });
  $("#choice").change();
</script>

<form >
  <span class="btn-group">
    <select name="select" data-bind="options: area" id="choice">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose     website</option>
    </select>
    <input id="editExistannotation" data-bind="value:     annotationList"  type="text" placeholder="Enter website"/>
  </span>
  <button id="buttonSave" type="submit"     data-bind="click:append" >Save</button>
</form>
<div id="labelList" class="btn-group" ></div>
```

However, this drop down method does NOT store these appends. Infact, it doesn't even add any items to the menu at all. I'd like it to add an item to the drop down, and save it using local storage, so when the user refreshes the page, the appends are still there.

So two issues, how to pass the url to the drop down, and how to make the drop down save appended items.

Also, I am not concerned over security issues at the moment.

Comment: Is this for a LIVE site or just for learning purposes? If it's for a LIVE site, don't use MD5.

Comment: It may become a live site, for the moment, learning purposes.

Comment: what do you mean, "send to dropdown"? Is the php code generating the page that contains the dropdown? If not, then you'd need an ajax call in the dropdown page to fetch the value from the server.

Comment: By 'send to drop down' I mean, pass the url to the drop down to be stored as an option in the menu.

Comment: So you mean the dropdown list of URLs is driven by a value in LocalStorage, and there is UI to add additional URLs. Correct?